# Rails - Accepts_nested_attributes_for mass assignment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

I am currently trying to set up a form with nested fields on a belongs_to relationship, but I am running into a mass assignment error. My code so far is as follows (some html removed):

Sale model:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer_attributes
  belongs_to :customer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for :sale, :url => sales_path do |sale| -%>
    <%= sale.fields_for :customer do |customer_builder| %>
      <%= render :partial => "customers/form", :locals => {:customer => customer_builder, :form_actions_visible => false} %>
    <% end -%>
  <% end -%>
```

customers/_form.html.erb

```
<fieldset>
  <label class="control-label">Customer Type</label>
  <%= collection_select(:customer, :customer_type_id, CustomerType.all, :id, :value, {}, {:class => "chzn-select"}) %>
</fieldset>
```

I believe this should allow me to create a Sale object, and a nested Customer object. The parameters being sent are (note some unrelated params are included):

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"qCjHoU9lO8VS060dXFHak+OMoE/GkTMZckO0c5SZLUU=",
"customer"=>{"customer_type_id"=>"1"},
"sale"=>{"customer"=>{"features_attributes"=>{"feature_type_id"=>"1",
"value"=>"jimmy"}}},
"vehicle"=>{"trim_id"=>"1",
"model_year_id"=>"1"}}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: customer
```

I can see why this might be the case, since :customer is not in the attr_accessible list for Sale - though shouldn't the form be sending customer_attributes instead of customer?

Any help / advice appreciated.

EDIT 1: As far as I can tell, attr_accessible in the Sale model should be covered with :customer_attributes - if anyone says different, please let me know.

EDIT 2: I have tried various permutations, but I can not seem to get the parameters to send customer_attributes instead of simply customer - perhaps I have missed a tag or used an incorrect tag somewhere in the forms above?

EDIT 3: I have found another question on SO that indicated a problem with the `:url =>` part on the form_for tag - the question was referring to a formtastic setup, but I'm wondering if that could be what is causing the problem here?

Comment: This guy had the same problem I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061217/rails-3-mass-assignment-errors-with-fields-for/12061461#12061461 . Read the last comment of the answer, it might help.

Comment: That question seems to have been because of some customer helpers, but there are no such helpers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to the answer here eventually. The key was this line:

```
<%= collection_select(:customer, :customer_type_id, CustomerType.all, :id, :value, {}, {:class => "chzn-select"}) %>
```

which needed to be changed to:

```
<%= customer.collection_select(:customer_type_id, CustomerType.all, :id, :value, {}, {:class => "chzn-select"}) %>
```

Once this was changed, everything fell into place.

Answer (score 4):

This might be the problem...  from the API docs:

> **Using with attr_accessible**
>
> The use of attr_accessible can interfere with nested attributes if
>   you’re not careful. For example, if the Member model above was using
>   attr_accessible like this:
>
> `attr_accessible :name`
>
> You would need to modify it to look like this:
>
> `attr_accessible :name, :posts_attributes`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#label-Using+with+attr_accessible

Comment: As far as I can tell I have covered this by adding :customer_attributes to attr_accessible on Sale - is this what you were referring to?