# Rails 3, many-to-many form using accepts_nested_attributes_for, how do I set up correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I have a many-to-many relationship between **Recipes** and **Ingredients**.  I am trying to build a form that allows me to *add an ingredient to a recipe*.

(Variants of this question have been asked repeatedly, I have spent hours on this, but am fundamentally confused by what `accepts_nested_attributes_for` does.)

Before you get scared by all the code below I hope you'll see it's really a basic question.  Here are the non-scary details...

#### Errors

When I display a form to create a recipe, I am getting the error "uninitialized constant Recipe::IngredientsRecipe", pointing to a line in my form partial

```
18:   <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>
```

If I change this line to make "ingredients" singular

```
<%= f.fields_for :ingredient do |i| %>
```

then the form displays, but when I save I get a mass assignment error `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ingredient`.

#### Models (in 3 files, named accordingly)

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :ingredient_id
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredients_recipes
  has_many :ingredients_recipes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients_recipes
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :recipe_id
  has_many :ingredients_recipes
  has_many :recipes, :through => :ingredients_recipes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients_recipes
end

class IngredientsRecipes < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :recipe

  attr_accessible :ingredient_id, :recipe_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end
```

#### Controllers

As RESTful resources generated by `rails generate scaffold`

#### And, because the plural of "recipe" is irregular, `inflections.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
    inflect.irregular 'recipe', 'recipes'
end
```

#### View (`recipes/_form.html.erb`)

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, "Recipe" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= i.label :name, "Ingredient" %><br />
      <%= i.collection_select :ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

#### Environment

- Rails 3.2.9
- ruby 1.9.3

#### Some things tried

If I change the view `f.fields_for :ingredient` then the form loads (it finds `Recipe::IngredientRecipe` correctly, but then when I save, I get a mass-assignment error as noted above.  Here's the log

```
Started POST "/recipes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-20 16:50:37 -0500
Processing by RecipesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/fMS6ua0atk7qcXwGy7NHQtuOnJqDzoW5P3uN9oHWT4=", "recipe"=>{"name"=>"Stewed Tomatoes", "ingredient"=>{"ingredient_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Create Recipe"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ingredient):
  app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:43:in `new'
  app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

and the failing lines in the controller is simply

```
@recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
```

So the params being passed, including the nested attributes, are incorrect in some way.  But I have tried lots of variants that fix-one-break-another.  What am I failing to understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to clues from all, I have found what was wrong with my approach.  Here's how I solved it.

I had originally tried with a simple HABTM many-to-many relationship, where the join table was named following standard Rails convention: `ingredients_recipes`.  Then I realized that in a way, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is designed for a 1-to-many relationship.  So I converted to using `has_many_through`, creating a model `IngredientsRecipes`.

That name was the core problem, because Rails needs to be able to convert from plural to singular when using `build` to create form elements.  This caused it to look for the non-existant class `Recipe::IngredientsRecipe`.  When I changed my form so it used `fields_for :ingredient` the form displayed, but still failed to save with a mass assignment error.  It even failed when I added `:ingredients_attributes` to `attr_accessible`.  It still failed when I added `@recipe.ingredients.build` to `RecipesController#new`.

Changing the model to a singular form was the final key to resolve the problem.  `IngredientsRecipe` would have worked, but I chose `RecipeIngredients`, as it makes more sense.

So to summarize:

- can't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `has_and_belongs_to_many`; need `has_many` with `through` option.  (Thanks @kien_thanh)
- adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for` creates a accessor that must be added to `attr_accessible` in the form `<plural-foreign-model>_attributes`, e.g. in `Recipe` I added `attr_accessible :name, :ingredients_attributes` (Thanks @beerlington)
- before displaying the form in the `new` method of the controller, must call `build` on the foreign model after creating a new instance, as in `3.times { @recipe.ingredients.build }`.  This results in HTML having names like `recipe[ingredients_attributes][0][name]` (Thanks @bravenewweb)
- join model must be singular, as with all models.  (All me :-).

Answer (score 4):

If you inspect the form that is generated, you'll notice that the nested fields have a name like "ingredients_attributes". The reason you're getting the mass-assignment error is because you need to add these fields to the `attr_accessible` declaration.

Something like this should fix it (you'll need to doublecheck the field names):

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :ingredients_attributes
  #...
end
```

**Update**: There's a [similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12064105/167614)

Comment: Thanks for the clues but perhaps my brain is just addled from reading and reading and reading the docs :-P -- when I inspect the HTML of the form where I am adding ingredients to a recipe, the select list is named `recipe[ingredient][id]` which is parsed into the params as `"recipe"=>{"name"=>"Stewed Tomatoes", "ingredient"=>{"ingredient_id"=>"1"}}`.  I know that's wrong, but I am not sure what is right.  Is `:ingredients_attributes` kind of a collection of attributes of the Ingredients model?  I just don't have a good mental model of what Rails is looking for, or even an example.  Thanks.

Comment: This was a big clue, but only part of the answer, I have found answer and will add it below.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Leave the call as

```
<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>
```

But before that do

```
<% @recipe.ingredients.build %>
```

Im guessing that will allow your form to be created the right way, but there are likely other errors with your models, I can look @ it more in detail when I have more time if its still not working, but:

As far as what accepts_nested_attributes_for does, when you pass in a correctly formatted params hash to the Model.new or Model.create or Model.update, it allows those attributes on the related model to be saved if they are in the params hash. In addition though, you do need to make the attributes accessible if they are unaccessible in the parent model as stated by beerlington.

Comment: Thank you!  I am working now to create the simplest possible case, which may start with a one-to-many case (rather than my many-to-many case).  Once I grok `accepts_nested_attributes_for` a bit more, I'll be less of an idiot than I feel like I am now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need set up a one-to-many association, one recipe has many ingredients and one ingredient belongs to one recipe, so your model look like:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :ingredients_attributes
  has_many :ingredients

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :recipe_id
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

You are built right form, so I don't write it again here. Now in your new and create controller will be like this:

```
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new

  # This is create just one select field on form
  @recipe.ingredients.build 

  # Create two select field on form
  2.times { @recipe.ingredients.build }

  # If you keep code above for new method, now you create 3 select field
end

def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
  if @recipe.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

How does `params[:recipe]` look like? If you just have one select field, maybe like this:

```
params = { recipe: { name: "Stewed Tomatoes", ingredients_attributes: [ { id: 1 } ] } }
```

If you have 2 ingredient select field:

```
params = { recipe: { name: "Stewed Tomatoes", ingredients_attributes: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 } ] } }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am quite sure the one-to-many relationship will work, except that's not how my data is modelled (e.g. "tomatoes" are an ingredient in "Stewed Tomatoes" and "Marinara Sauce" recipes; "Marinara Sauce" has "tomatoes" and "garlic" ingredients).  Based on the naming I am seeing in the one-to-many cases, I am beginning to think either 1) `accepts_nested_attributes_for` doesn't work for M-2-M relationships, or 2) I haven't figured out how yet :-).  When I am done, I will write a blog post with a clear and simple answer, since there's *nothin'* out there on Google.

Comment: I believe that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` only work for one-one and one-to-many, as in [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) they are also not mention about many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Lookin' that way, and now I am figuring out why, and if there's a way to make it work.  Several other questions on SO suggest that people *have* gotten it to work.

Comment: I think I don't need to build nested form for many-to-many. In basic, it's still one-to-many association if you use `has_many, :through` in two model. I think that is reason why Rails did not provide `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for many-to-many relationship.

Comment: I have found the solution to the problem, and it *does work* for many_to_many. See below.